# SocketException bad file descriptor when reading from InputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream

I am attempting to build an android application where a user can create a new account and have that account creation executed by a server and the info added to a database.

After the server completes (or fails to complete) this task, I want a response sent back to the client indicating success or failure of the task; I am opening an `inputstream` and an `outputstream` from the same socket that is a member of my async task class.

It seems that the code executes fine while sending from client to server and the server receives everything correctly. But when the client is receiving the response back from the server, I run into an error:

```
09-02 15:58:02.266 30979-32154/com.example.zemcd.messagebottle E/NewAccountTask: error connecting
    java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:588)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap0(PlainSocketImpl.java)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
        at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:233)
        at com.example.zemcd.messagebottle.NewAccountTask.doInBackground(NewAccountTask.java:50)
        at com.example.zemcd.messagebottle.NewAccountTask.doInBackground(NewAccountTask.java:17)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
        at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:189)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
```

Here is the code for my android clients asynctask, I have indicated where the error occurs:

```
public class NewAccountTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private static final String TAG = "NewAccountTask";
private static final String AUTH_KEY = "9LEF1D97001X!@:";
private static final String REQUEST_NEW_ACCOUNT = "0";
private static final int PORT = 5555;

private String mContactId;
private String mPassword;
private Context mContext;


private Socket mSocket;
private String response;

public NewAccountTask(String contactId, String password, Context context){
    mContactId = contactId + ":";
    mPassword = password + ":";
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try{
        mSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.111", PORT);
        OutputStream out = mSocket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in  = mSocket.getInputStream();
        //write key to server
        byte[] buffer = (AUTH_KEY + mContactId + mPassword + REQUEST_NEW_ACCOUNT).getBytes();
        out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        //i posted a log message here this one runs
        int c;
        while((c = in.read()) != -1) { <--ERROR OCCURS HERE!
            response += (char) c;
        }
        //and here this one never runs

        in.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "connection success!");
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Void result){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Here is the method used by the server to send the response:

```
    public void sendResponse(byte[] response) {
    OutputStream out;
    try {
        out = sock.getOutputStream();
        out.write(response, 0, response.length);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: If the read loop never exits it can only because the peer isn't closing the connection. Did it throw an exception?

Comment: @EJP no. It throws no exception. It just never exits.

Comment: Sigh. Did the *peer* throw an exception, instead of closing the connection?

Comment: @EJP no. The peer throws no exception. It just stops. The server starts receiving but never seems to read or write any data.

Comment: So the *server* has a similar read loop, that will never terminate until the *client* closes the connection. This is not a feasible approach. You need to send and read *lines*, for example.

Comment: @EJP Ok. I will look into that. Could you maybe give me a small example of what I am methods I would want to use.

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine()`, and `BufferedWriter.newLine()`.

Comment: @EJP after trying this i still seem to be having the same issue.

Comment: @EJP actually, after having a little more patience it is working. but it is just very slow. any idea how to make this perform better? and also now i am receiving old messages. if i shut down the server and start it again i imidiately recieve and old message.

Comment: You're going to have to post your current code, in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) of the `Socket#getOutputStream` class :

> **getOutputStream**
>
> OutputStream getOutputStream ()
>
> Returns an output stream for this socket.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the resulting output
>   stream delegates all of its operations to the channel. If the channel
>   is in non-blocking mode then the output stream's write operations will
>   throw an IllegalBlockingModeException.
>
> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

**What needs to be noted here is :**

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

And in your code, after you write to the ouput stream:

`out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);`

you closed the output stream

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Which according to docs, closes the socket and hence the associated `InputStream`.  And thus the exception.

Just close the socket connection after both of the operations are performed, instead of closing each stream seperately.

Also note that `flush()` is pretty useless before `close()`.

Comment: Note that this is a bug in Android. It should have thrown `SocketException: socket closed`.

Comment: @EJP : According to limited knowlegde I have, it looks like the exception is correct. As per docs, `close()` will close the socket too, and hence will close the associated `InputStream` and `read()` operation (which actually throws the exception) is on the closed `InputStream` (so not really directly related to the socket) and the exception in the question is okay for a closed `InputStream`. Am I missing something ? Can you please correct me ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge i have done as you suggested but i am having a new problem. when i attempt to close both streams after performing both operations the application gets stuck on this on the read operation. i am posting an edit to my code pointing out where it gets stuck.

Comment: It is correct that it throws an exception, but it is not correct that it throws *this* exception. It should do what I stated, like the Oracle JRE. It *is* related *directly* to the socket, *by* the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

i used the suggestions in the other answers as well as the comments posted for this question to solve this problem. however one main issue still remained. if one a one attempt at sending a message fails then the server would never complete and send a response. the method i used to solve this was to set a timeout on the socket that was connecting. i replaced the read loops with:

```
mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.setSoTimeout(500);
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.111", PORT);
mSocket.connect(socketAddress);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
Log.d(TAG, "streams aquired");

out.write(AUTH_KEY + mContactId + mPassword + REQUEST_NEW_ACCOUNT);
Log.d(TAG, "data sent");
out.newLine();
out.flush();

Log.d(TAG, "read began");
response = in.readLine();
out.close();
in.close();
Log.d(TAG, "streams closed");

Log.i(TAG, "connection success!");
```

and used a public interface to OnFailureListener to notify the calling activity of a socket timing out.